How do I change the font of label roles for the form layout in PyQt5?
I want all the text in a window I'm generating in PyQT5 to be courier. However, when I add rows to a form layout and add the label roles, these labels do not appear in courier. Here is my code:
self.vertical.addLayout(self.form)
self.user_name = QLineEdit(self)
self.user_name.setFont(QtGui.QFont('Courier', 15))
self.password = QLineEdit(self)
self.password.setFont(QtGui.QFont('Courier', 15))
self.form.addRow('username', self.user_name)
self.form.addRow('password', self.password)

From the code, I cannot get the form labels 'username' and 'password' to be in courier. There must be a simple fix, but I am just not finding it. I appreciate anyone taking the time to help!  See the following picture and note that 'username' and 'password' are not in courier:


Is the font intended to be exactly the same for all widgets? Note that you could use setFont() for the dialog (or even the QApplication), which will apply to all its children.

@musicamante, thank you! that works too.

Note that, when manually setting the same font on different widgets, you could just create it once (instead of declaring it every time) and use setFont() with its reference.

Try something like this:
from PyQt5 import QtGui, QtWidgets

class MyWindow(QtWidgets.QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        self.form = QtWidgets.QFormLayout()
        self.vertical = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(self)
        self.vertical.addLayout(self.form)

        self.user_name = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(self)
        self.user_name.setFont(QtGui.QFont('Courier', 15))
        self.password = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(self)
        self.password.setFont(QtGui.QFont('Courier', 15))

        # Create labels with the desired font
        username_label = QtWidgets.QLabel('username')
        username_label.setFont(QtGui.QFont('Courier', 15))
        password_label = QtWidgets.QLabel('password')
        password_label.setFont(QtGui.QFont('Courier', 15))

        self.form.addRow(username_label, self.user_name)
        self.form.addRow(password_label, self.password)

        self.setLayout(self.vertical)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication([])
    window = MyWindow()
    window.show()
    app.exec_()

I get as a result:


of course. brilliant idea, @Mahrez BenHamad
